# Is a ul allowed inslide an inline li in html or xhtml?

Tags: html, css

Note the li with child ul is display:inline
 - code example as follows

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.nav_main li { display: inline }
ul.nav_submenu li { display: block }
</style>

<ul class="nav_main">
    <li>Item 1
        <ul class="nav_submenu">
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: css styles should not be put in script tags... you wrote : <script>
ul.nav_main li { display: inline }
</script> 
Next it doesnt matter what you do in the css , it is not related to html (which doctype ? ) or xhtml.

Comment: furthermore , a simple answer to your question is to validate your page with the validators online , did you do that ?

Comment: Oh I should have proof read this better. Ive fixed the bugs in the code no didnt try online validator ill try that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS does not affect validity of HTML source. It may however cause unpredictable results, as the browser try their best to place a UL inside of an inline element (even though it's valid!)

Any way, you're always welcome **[to check it yourself](http://validator.w3.org/)**

Comment: removed my almost identical comment and +1

Comment: @Truth does this answer still apply for my new revised version above with block element ul inside inline li?

Answer (score 1):

I see no problems with XHTML 1.0. If you want to check, you can use the W3C Validator:
http://validator.w3.org/check

Therefor you need a dummy page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
ul.nav_main li { display: inline }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav_main">
    <li>Item 1
        <ul class="nav_submenu">
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

No errors on W3C Validator

Comment: Sorry Cromax I typed out my html wrong I actually wanted a block element inside an inline as per my updated revision above

Answer (score 0):

Nesting of `<ul>` is allowed in CSS

If you are trying to get horizontal `nav-main` with vertical `nav_submenu`, you should have `display: inline-block` for `ul.nav-main > li`

```
<style>
    ul.nav_main li { display: inline-block }
    ul.nav_submenu li { display: block }
</style>

<ul class="nav_main">
    <li>Item 1
        <ul class="nav_submenu">
            <li>Option 1.1</li>
            <li>Option 1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2
        <ul class="nav_submenu">
            <li>Option 2.1</li>
            <li>Option 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

Tested in Firefox 11 and Chrome 17 on Linux

Comment: I like the solution Evlis however I have a feeling the direct child symbol you have used is not a cross browser solution

Comment: Fair enough. I did not know this was an issue. I updated the answer and here is the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3wfpb/1/ 
Hope this helps